# Dependence of irreducbiblity of $(\pi,V)$ on $V$ for representations of $SO(2,\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: representation-theory

Consider the natural representations of $SO(2,\mathbb{R})$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $$\pi:SO(2,\mathbb{R})\times\mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2:(g,v)\mapsto g\cdot v$$$$\rho:SO(2,\mathbb{R})\times\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2:(g,v)\mapsto g\cdot v.$$

I would like to show that $\pi$ is reducible and $\rho$ is irreducible.

Claim: $\pi$ is reducible.

It should be clear that $W_1=\text{span}\{(1,i)\}$ and $W_2=\text{span}\{(1,-i)\}$ are invariant one-dim subspaces. Hence $\pi$ is not irreducible. A question I have here is, is this all the irreducible components, is $\mathbb{C}^2=W_1\oplus W_2$.

Claim: $\rho$ is irreducbile.

My first idea was to to show that this is a one dimesional representation and hence by schur irreducible. But that did not seem to work. Is that the correct approach or what way should I continue?

New attempt:

To show $(\rho,\mathbb{R}^2)$ is irreducible we muts show that $0$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are the only invariant subspaces. Invariant subspaces are linear, so I think the only possible candidates for such a space are lines through the origin. But then this is clearly not invariant under the action of $SO(2)$. Therefore $(\rho,\mathbb{R}^2)$ is irreducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly observed that $\pi$ is not irreducible by writing the representation as a direct sum of two one-dimensional representations, which are irreducible because they are one-dimensional.

The irreducibility of $\rho$ follows from the following observation. Consider the matrix $A \in \text{SO}(2, \mathbb R)$ rotating every vector by an angle of $\pi/2$. More concretely,
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Let $v\in \mathbb R^2$ be any non-zero vector. Then $Av$ is linearly independent from $v$ (it is even orthogonal), so $v$ does not lie in any one-dimensional invariant subspace. Since $v$ was arbitrary, irreducibility follows.

Comment: This is a very good answer. You answered the question and made sure to explain parts in particular I was unsure on for $\pi$, and you given a slick answer for $\rho$. May I ask, is my "new attempt" correct?

Comment: @Emily My "slick answer" is basically your new attempt, but with elaboration on the "clearly" :)